# Zip encryption, individual files or the whole directory/file tree of the zip archive

Tags: encryption, compression, zip, archiving

As an example fuse-zip shows a directory list, when executed on an encrypted zip archive. The individual files then cannot be read or written to. But the directory tree and the individual file names are visible. Which is according to scenario not advisable. Gpg would not show a directory structure of a tar.gz or a tgz file as a contrary example.

This limits the zip encryption from revealing directory structure when dropped on a remote site as another example.

Is there a solution to this exposure within the binary of zip, or does one have to rely on a next binary thus making the zip encryption solution un-interesting in the scenario as to conceal the directory structure within the zip archive additionally to the files being encrypted individually.

Answer (score 2):

“Standard” ZIP encryption is terribly weak and, as you discovered, only affects file contents, not the directory structure. There is no way to change this if the result should still be a ZIP file that ZIP tools can access.

You can still encrypt an entire ZIP archive using GPG, like you did with a gzipped Tar archive. To work with data inside, you will need to decrypt it again using GPG.

The best solution is to just not use ZIP. Instead, use a more modern archive format like 7zip’s 7z format. 7zip has strong encryption built-in and you can decide whether file names should be encrypted or not. There may be similar formats that I’m not aware of, too.